# How to increment a C pointer by two

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my sample code:

```
float *dstptr;
float *srcptr;
float A[100];
float B[32];
int main(void)
  {
 int i=0;
 while(i < NUM_ITERATION)
  {
    srcptr = &B[0];
    for(i=0; i< 32; i++)
    {
        *dstptr++ = *srcptr++;
        dstptr = circptr(dstptr,1,(float *)&A[0], 100);
    }
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Here `*dstptr++ = *srcptr++;` increments both `dstptr` and `srcptr` by one once. But I need to increment them by two.
Is there any clue how to do this in C?

Comment: try with `ptr += 2`

Comment: Do you mean *dstptr++ =  2 ?

Comment: I mean `dstptr += 2` or `srcptr += 2`

Comment: You never initialize `dstptr` before using it. That's bad.

Answer (score 3):

Its called [pointer arithmetic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

And it allows you to do

```
dstptr += nOfElementsToSkip;
srcptr += nOfElementsToSkip;
*dstptr = *srcptr;
```

as well as incrementing. Or if you dont want to modify the pointer

```
*(dstptr+nOfElementsToSkip) = *(srcptr+nOfElementsToSkip); // Same as
dstptr[nOfElementsToSkip] = srcptr[nOfElementsToSkip];     // This is more clear
```

**EDIT**:

In your case change `nOfElementsToSkip` to `2`.

Also as @unwind mentioned, you have to assign some dynamical memory to pointers otherwise dereferencing would cause undefined behavior.

```
float *dstptr = malloc(sizeof(float) * NUM_ITERATION);
// Do something with pointer
// And if you dont need them anymore
free(dstptr);
```

Comment: Never write `*(pointer + index)`, always use `pointer[index]`. Means exactly the same, but is so much clearer.

Comment: In OP's example code, the initialization would probably be `dstptr = &B[0];`

Answer (score 3):

Preferably by not mixing several operators in the same expression, which is dangerous and sometimes hard to read. Instead, do this:

```
*dstptr = *srcptr;
dstptr += 2;
srcptr += 2;
```

Alternatively, use the most readable form, if this is an option:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i+=2)
{
  ...
  dstptr[i] = srcptr[i];
  ...
}
```